# JS: draggable object speed

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, konva

I want to slow down speed of the draggable HTML object to make it kind of lazy dragging.

[image]

Is there any way to implement this feature with native HTML/CSS?

Or may be there are some existing JS libraries which have such ability?

Can't find any library with such simple feature..

Comment: actually you can implement the drag and drop algorithm using mouse down, move, up events then u can multiply the movement by a factor of let's say .33 it will make it slower than cursor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but if you just decrease draggable object position relative to mouse it will simply restrict object position area.

Comment: if you want to make it lazy then u can add the transition property without multiplying the movement by any factor :) hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made one possible solution but also not forgot to share ;)

The point is to apply mouse position to the circle on `mousemove` event to emulate dragging effect.

Also I've added `transition` CSS property to the circle for smooth movement.

The main thing here is to update circle position not continuously right in the `mousemove` event listener. But in case with `transition` property you should update circle position at some intervals to give CSS `transition` time to animate circle displacement smoothly. Otherwise CSS `transition` animation will be overloaded by continuous update from `mousemeove` event and become glitchy.

```js
var cirlce = document.querySelector('.circle');

function getTranslateX(myElement) {
   var style = window.getComputedStyle(myElement);
   var matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(style.webkitTransform);
   return matrix.m41; // 'm41' is translateX position
}

function getTranslateY(myElement) {
   var style = window.getComputedStyle(myElement);
   var matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(style.webkitTransform);
   return matrix.m42; // 'm42' is translateY position
}

var mouseDown = false;
var mousePos = {
   x: 0,
   y: 0,
}
var mouseLastPos = {
   x: 0,
   y: 0,
}
var circlePos = {
   x: getTranslateX(cirlce),
   y: getTranslateY(cirlce),
}

window.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
   mouseDown = false;
   circlePos = {
      x: getTranslateX(cirlce),
      y: getTranslateY(cirlce),
   }
});
window.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
   mouseDown = true;
   mouseLastPos.x = e.clientX;
   mouseLastPos.y = e.clientY;
});
window.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
   mousePos.x = e.clientX;
   mousePos.y = e.clientY;
   if (mouseDown) {
      // cirlce.style.transform = 'translateX('+(mousePos.x-mouseLastPos.x+circlePos.x)+'px) translateY('+(mousePos.y-mouseLastPos.y+circlePos.y)+'px)'; // doesn't work with 'transition' CSS property
   }
});

// main trick here to make 'transition' work properly
setInterval(() => {
   if (mouseDown) {
      cirlce.style.transform = 'translateX('+(mousePos.x-mouseLastPos.x+circlePos.x)+'px) translateY('+(mousePos.y-mouseLastPos.y+circlePos.y)+'px)';
   }
}, 50);
```

```css
.circle {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background-color: red;
   border: 2px solid black;
   border-radius: 50%;
   transform: translateX(5px) translateY(5px);
   transition: transform 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```